# Как сделать пометку что список выпадающий?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через css маленький значок справа от ссылки

Comment: Приложите css код, что уже сделано по этому списку

Comment: кода нет, то что на картинке взял со стороннего сайта

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это вас направит в нужную сторону.

```css
.new-select select {
    border-radius: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 268px;
   }
.new-select {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 34px;
    background: url(http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/down-arrow_318-140021.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg) no-repeat right #fff;
    background-size: 24px;
    width: 280px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="new-select">
<select>
     <option>Выбор из выпадающего списка</option>
     <option>Второй выбор из выпадающего списка</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня стрелка от селекта отображается поверх вашей кастомной